Strange AWS CDK cyclic reference error, cannot identify source of cyclic dependency
To simplify, I have a VPC stack, an RDS stack, and a Lambda stack.
The Lambda stack depends on the RDS stack, and they both depend on the VPC stack, which is independent. However, AWS is telling me that the RDS and Lambda stacks depend on each other.
Here's how it looks in the main file:
vpc_stack = VPCStack(
    app,
    "VPCStack",
    env=cdk.Environment(account=Cfg.ACCOUNT, region=Cfg.REGION),
)

rds_stack = RDSStack(
    app,
    "RDSStack",
    vpc=vpc_stack.vpc,
    env=cdk.Environment(account=Cfg.ACCOUNT, region=Cfg.REGION),
)

main_lambda_stack = MainLambdaStack(
    app,
    "MainLambdaStack",
    vpc=vpc_stack.vpc,
    rds_proxy=rds_stack.rds_proxy,
    image_deleter_queue=bid_lambda_stack.image_deleter_queue,
    redis_cluster=redis_stack.redis_cluster,
    packages_bucket=s3_stack.packages_bucket,
    sg_redis=redis_stack.sg_redis,
    sg_rds_proxy=rds_stack.sg_rds_proxy,
    images_bucket=s3_stack.user_images_bucket,
    env=cdk.Environment(account=Cfg.ACCOUNT, region=Cfg.REGION),
)

And the error itself is:
    RuntimeError: Error: 'RDSStack' depends on 'MainLambdaStack' 
(RDSStack -> MainLambdaStack/LambdaSecurityGroup/Resource.GroupId). 
Adding this dependency (MainLambdaStack -> RDSStack/RDSProxy/Resource.Endpoint) 
would create a cyclic reference.

But I simply cannot find any Lambda dependency in the RDS stack.
For more context here's the entirety of the RDS stack:
class RDSStack(Stack):
    def __init__(
        self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, vpc: ec2.Vpc, **kwargs
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        # RDS security group
        sg_rds = ec2.SecurityGroup(
            self,
            "RDSSecurityGroup",
            vpc=vpc,
            description="Security group for RDS",
            security_group_name="rds-sg",
        )

        # RDS Proxy security group
        self.sg_rds_proxy = ec2.SecurityGroup(
            self,
            "RDSProxySecurityGroup",
            vpc=vpc,
            description="Security group for RDS Proxy",
            security_group_name="rds-proxy-sg",
        )

        # RDS instance
        rds_instance = rds.DatabaseInstance(  # noqa: F841
            self,
            "RDSInstance",
            engine=rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.postgres(
                version=rds.PostgresEngineVersion.VER_16_1
            ),
            instance_type=ec2.InstanceType.of(
                ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO
            ),
            vpc=vpc,
            vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(
                subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED
            ),
            security_groups=[sg_rds],
            removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.RETAIN,
            allocated_storage=20,
            auto_minor_version_upgrade=True,
            enable_performance_insights=True,
            monitoring_interval=Duration.minutes(10),
            backup_retention=Duration.days(7),
        )

        # RDS Proxy
        self.rds_proxy = rds.DatabaseProxy(  # noqa: F841
            self,
            "RDSProxy",
            vpc=vpc,
            vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(
                subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED
            ),
            security_groups=[self.sg_rds_proxy],
            db_proxy_name="rds-proxy",
            proxy_target=rds.ProxyTarget.from_instance(rds_instance),
            secrets=[rds_instance.secret],
        )

        # RDS ingress from RDS Proxy
        sg_rds.add_ingress_rule(
            ec2.Peer.security_group_id(self.sg_rds_proxy.security_group_id),
            ec2.Port.tcp(5432),
            "Allow PostgreSQL traffic from RDS Proxy security group",
        )

Any help would be appreciated.
EDIT: Adding the Main Lamba stack for extra context (it's quite large, but I don't know what to cut off for a MRE)
class MainLambdaStack(Stack):

    def __init__(
        self,
        scope: Construct,
        construct_id: str,
        vpc: ec2.Vpc,
        rds_proxy: rds.DatabaseProxy,
        image_deleter_queue: sqs.Queue,
        redis_cluster: elasticache.CfnCacheCluster,
        packages_bucket: s3.Bucket,
        sg_redis: ec2.SecurityGroup,
        sg_rds_proxy: ec2.SecurityGroup,
        images_bucket: s3.Bucket,
        **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        # company lambda security group
        sg_company_lambda = ec2.SecurityGroup(
            self,
            "companyLambdaSecurityGroup",
            vpc=vpc,
            description="Security group for company Lambda",
            security_group_name="company-lambda-sg",
        )

        # company lambda environment variables
        DB_HOST = rds_proxy.endpoint
        IMAGE_DELETER_QUEUE_URL = image_deleter_queue.queue_url
        REDIS_HOST = redis_cluster.attr_redis_endpoint_address

        env_vars = {
            "DB_FORCE_ROLLBACK": "False",
            "DB_HOST": DB_HOST,
            "DB_PORT": "5432",
            "DB_SCHEMA": "companyMVP_DEV",
            "ENV_STATE": "DEV",
            "IMAGE_DELETER_QUEUE_URL": IMAGE_DELETER_QUEUE_URL,
            "LOG_LEVEL": "DEBUG",
            "REDIS_HOST": REDIS_HOST,
            "REDIS_PORT": "6379",
        }

        # Execution role
        multi_service_role = iam.Role(
            self,
            "LambdaMultiServiceRole",
            assumed_by=iam.ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
            managed_policies=[
                iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name(
                    "AmazonElastiCacheFullAccess"
                ),
                iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name("AmazonS3FullAccess"),
                iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name("AmazonSESFullAccess"),
                iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name("AmazonSQSFullAccess"),
                iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name("AWSLambdaExecute"),
                iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name(
                    "SecretsManagerReadWrite"
                ),
            ],
            role_name="lambda-multi-service-role",
        )

        # Add logs policy
        multi_service_role.add_to_policy(
            statement=iam.PolicyStatement(
                actions=[
                    "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                    "logs:CreateLogStream",
                    "logs:PutLogEvents",
                ],
                resources=[f"arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:{Cfg.ACCOUNT}:*"],
                effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            )
        )

        # Add Cognito policy
        multi_service_role.add_to_policy(
            statement=iam.PolicyStatement(
                actions=[
                    "cognito-identity:GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity",
                    "cognito-identity:GetId",
                    "cognito-identity:GetCredentialsForIdentity",
                ],
                resources=["*"],
                effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            )
        )

        # Add RDS Proxy policy
        multi_service_role.add_to_policy(
            statement=iam.PolicyStatement(
                actions=[
                    "rds-db:connect",
                ],
                # CHECK HERE IF SHIT DONT WORK
                resources=[f"arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:{Cfg.ACCOUNT}:*/*"],
                effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            )
        )

        # Add X-ray policy
        multi_service_role.add_to_policy(
            statement=iam.PolicyStatement(
                actions=[
                    "xray:PutTraceSegments",
                    "xray:PutTelemetryRecords",
                ],
                resources=["*"],
                effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            )
        )

        # Add VPC Access policy
        multi_service_role.add_to_policy(
            statement=iam.PolicyStatement(
                actions=[
                    "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                    "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                    "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                ],
                resources=["*"],
                effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            )
        )

        # company lambda function
        lambda_fn = _lambda.Function(
            self,
            "companyLambda",
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_12,
            handler="main.handler",
            memory_size=1024,
            vpc=vpc,
            security_groups=[sg_company_lambda],
            vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(
                subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED
            ),
            environment=env_vars,
            timeout=Duration.seconds(30),
            role=multi_service_role,
            code=_lambda.Code.from_bucket(packages_bucket, "main_lambda.zip"),
        )

        # Add alias
        self.lambda_alias = _lambda.Alias(
            self,
            "MainLambdaAlias",
            alias_name="DEV",
            version=lambda_fn.current_version,
            provisioned_concurrent_executions=1,
        )

        # Add alias ARN to parameter store
        ssm.StringParameter(
            self,
            "main_lambda_alias_arn",
            parameter_name="/cdk/main_lambda/alias_arn",
            string_value=self.lambda_alias.function_arn,
        )

        # Parameter extension layer
        parameters_layer = _lambda.LayerVersion.from_layer_version_arn(
            self,
            "ParametersLayer",
            layer_version_arn="arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:177933569100:layer:AWS-Parameters-and-Secrets-Lambda-Extension:11",
        )
        # Add parameter extension layer to lambda function
        lambda_fn.add_layers(parameters_layer)

        # Redis ingress from company Lambda
        sg_redis.add_ingress_rule(
            ec2.Peer.security_group_id(sg_company_lambda.security_group_id),
            ec2.Port.tcp(6379),
            "Allow Redis traffic from company Lambda security group",
        )

        # RDS Proxy ingress from company Lambda
        sg_rds_proxy.add_ingress_rule(
            ec2.Peer.security_group_id(sg_company_lambda.security_group_id),
            ec2.Port.tcp(5432),
            "Allow PostgreSQL traffic from company Lambda security group",
        )

        # Create a new SES domain identity
        domain_identity = ses.EmailIdentity(  # noqa F841
            self, "DomainIdentity", identity=ses.Identity.domain("company.io")
        )

        # Create cognito identity pool provider
        cognito_identity_pool = cognito.CfnIdentityPool(  # noqa F841
            self,
            "CognitoIdentityPool",
            allow_unauthenticated_identities=False,
            identity_pool_name="company-verified-users",
            developer_provider_name="company.io",
        )

        # Create cognito identity pool role
        cognito_identity_pool_role = iam.Role(  # noqa F841
            self,
            "CognitoIdentityPoolRole",
            assumed_by=iam.FederatedPrincipal(
                federated="cognito-identity.amazonaws.com",
                conditions={
                    "StringEquals": {
                        "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": cognito_identity_pool.ref
                    }
                },
                assume_role_action="sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            ),
        )

        # Add get credentialts for identity policy
        cognito_identity_pool_role.add_to_policy(
            statement=iam.PolicyStatement(
                actions=["cognito-identity:GetCredentialsForIdentity"],
                resources=["*"],
                effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            )
        )

        images_bucket_name = images_bucket.bucket_name

        # Add S3 get object policy
        cognito_identity_pool_role.add_to_policy(
            statement=iam.PolicyStatement(
                actions=["s3:GetObject"],
                resources=[f"arn:aws:s3:::{images_bucket_name}/*"],
                effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            )
        )


You're passing resources from other stacks to the RDSStack, do any of those depend on the Lambda Stack?

@Maurice I'm only passing the VPC stack to the RDS stack, which doesn't depend on anything, as most other things depend on it.

Ah, my bad - mixed up the Lambda and RDS stacks

Add the Main stack to the question as well

@gshpychka Okay, added the Main Lambda stack for more context.

I would say that these commands are adding the reference from RDS / Redis stacks to the lambda stack
# Redis ingress from company Lambda
        sg_redis.add_ingress_rule(
            ec2.Peer.security_group_id(sg_company_lambda.security_group_id),
            ec2.Port.tcp(6379),
            "Allow Redis traffic from company Lambda security group",
        )

        # RDS Proxy ingress from company Lambda
        sg_rds_proxy.add_ingress_rule(
            ec2.Peer.security_group_id(sg_company_lambda.security_group_id),
            ec2.Port.tcp(5432),
            "Allow PostgreSQL traffic from company Lambda security group",
        )

Sometimes CDK construct source code makes dependency other way around than your code has constructor injections between stacks.
You can check the source code of the CDK constructs in GitHub, for example for https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/205163fc0d2cac84d3d746a98c393e137f0e2388/packages/aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2/lib/security-group.ts#L84C1-L100C4 it is
  public addIngressRule(peer: IPeer, connection: Port, description?: string, remoteRule?: boolean) {
    if (description === undefined) {
      description = `from ${peer.uniqueId}:${connection}`;
    }

    const { scope, id } = this.determineRuleScope(peer, connection, 'from', remoteRule);

    // Skip duplicates
    if (scope.node.tryFindChild(id) === undefined) {
      new CfnSecurityGroupIngress(scope, id, {
        groupId: this.securityGroupId,
        ...peer.toIngressRuleConfig(),
        ...connection.toRuleJson(),
        description,
      });
    }
  }

You can either refactor your stacks to have a networking stack where all security groups are defined and rules sorted out, or you can create the CfnSecurityGroupIngress yourself in the lambda stack and not pass it to method of the security group in the db stack.
Also, you will probably face same issue with redis stack later.

The error I get happens during cdk synth on any of my stacks, so I can't view the json output since it doesn't complete. Is there any way I can resolve this, perhaps re-wiring the security groups rules in some way?

Also, please note that I am aware the Lambda stack is dependent on the RDS stack, that is expected, what is unexpected is the RDS stack being dependent on the Lambda stack, which cause the error and is unintended.

Sorry, did not realized synth will cause error too. I provided solutions I think would work, but did not had opportunity to try out and test myself.
